Is my form submission being prevented by SWR?
I am using nextjs and incorporating SWR for some client side data rendering for an edit page. I can get the data through the fetcher but for some reason my values wont update or setState unless I click on the form submission twice. The code as follows:
export default function Edit({ params }) {
  let [title, setTitle] = useState();
  let [body, setBody] = useState();
  const router = useRouter();

  const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json());

  const sumbitForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!title) {
      setTitle(data.title);
    }
    console.log(title);

    if (!body) {
      setTags(data.body);
    }
    console.log(body);
  };

  const id = params.forumId;
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    `http://localhost:3000/api/forum/${id}`,
    fetcher,
  );

  if (error) {
    return <div>failed to load</div>;
  }
  if (!data) {
    return <div>loading...</div>;
  }
  if (data) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="grid items-center min-h-screen px-4 space-y-4 md:px-6">
          <div className="space-y-2">
            <label className="form-label" htmlFor="title">
              Title
            </label>
            <Input
              id="title"
              onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
              defaultValue={data.title}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className="space-y-2">
            <label className="form-label" htmlFor="body">
              Body
            </label>
            <Textarea
              id="body"
              required
              onChange={(e) => setBody(e.target.value)}
              defaultValue={data.body}
              rows={10}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="space-y-2">
            <Button id="submitBtn" type="submit" onClick={sumbitForm}>
              Submit Button
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

my console logs just look like this {title: 'edited title', body: undefined}. it isn't until I click on the submit button again that the console log is able to pick up the fields from the swr fetcher on the state of the remaining field: {title: 'edited title', body: 'The body of the original post'}. Any ideas why it takes 2 clicks to get the loaded data to associate to the value of the state?
